# Current Output for ZVS Flyback Transformer

Tags: voltage, high-voltage, flyback, zvs

What is the typical current output for high voltage of ZVS flyback transformer or how to properly measure it?

Update with the schematic, the fly-back transformer is typical one used in old CRT TV;

[image: ZVS Flyback Driver]

Comment: Somewhere betweeen 1 uA and 100 amps. Show a schematic if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Secondary winding can give an idea.

Measure the diameter of the secondary winding (d), then calculate its cross sectional area via \$A = \pi \ d^2/4\$. If secondary winding consists of paralleled multiple windings then you need to calculate total cross sectional area.

Maximum allowed continuous current can be approximated from \$I_M = J \cdot A\$, where \$J\$ is the current density with an assumption of \$J=420\ Amperes/cm^2\$. *(Actually this \$J\$ value is valid for almost all SMPS power transformers as well)*.